# Need event for user clicking on a tab in Android

Tags: android, tabs

I need to capture events when the user clicks on a tab in a `TabHost`. Something similar to `OnTabChangeListener`, but `OnTabChangeListener` only fires when the tab changes, not when it stays the same.

Comment: I'v never seen a way to do this. Why do you need to listen for clicks to the active tab?

Answer (score 0):

`OnClickListener`?